# How do I display foreach output without define the array id manually?

Tags: php, arrays

[Example of my arrays & output](http://codepad.org/6OFkbWoc)

How do I manage my foreach without to write it manually on each loops? Because I dont't know the depth of child users will choose.

```
$array['0']['children']
$array['1']['children']
$array['2']['children']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a recursive function to call on your array.

example:

```
<html><body>
<h1>test</h1>
<?php

$array = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id' => 1, 
        'name' => 'Sizes',
        'parent' => 0,
        'children' => array(
            '0' => array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'S', 'parent' => 1),
            '1' => array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'L', 'parent' => 1),
            '2' => array('id' => 6, 'name' => 'M', 'parent' => 1)
        )
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Colors',
        'parent' => 0,
        'children' => array(
            '0' => array('id' => 7, 'name' => 'White', 'parent' => 2),
            '1' => array('id' => 8, 'name' => 'Black', 'parent' => 2)
        )
    ),
     '2' => array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Types',
        'parent' => 0,
        'children' => array(
            '0' => array('id' => 9, 'name' => 'Polyester', 'parent' => 3),
            '1' => array('id' => 10, 'name' => 'Lycra', 'parent' => 3)
        )
    )
 );


function my_recurse($array, $depth=0) {
   //to avoid infinite depths check for a high value
   if($depth>100) {  return; }  

   //


   foreach ($array as $id => $child) {
        echo "Array element $id = " . $child['id'] . " " . $child['name'] . "<br>\n";    //whatever you wanna output
     // test if got ghildren
     if(isset($child['children'])) {   
         my_recurse($child['children'], $depth+1); // Call to self on infinite depth. 
     }
   }
}



my_recurse($array);

?>
</body></html>
```

Please note! Always use a depth check in your function to avoid infinite recursion.

This gives the following output in my browser:

### test

Array element 0 = 1 Sizes

Array element 0 = 4 S

Array element 1 = 5 L

Array element 2 = 6 M

Array element 1 = 2 Colors

Array element 0 = 7 White

Array element 1 = 8 Black

Array element 2 = 3 Types

Array element 0 = 9 Polyester

Array element 1 = 10 Lycra

Comment: I've modified it a bit. This script runs fine on my server

Comment: The warnings you get has to do with checking if there is a child or not. I'll update the script with that even though I just intended to show you how to use recursion ;-)

Comment: if i set `error_reporting(0)` and it works fine. how to avoid the `Undefined index: children`?

Comment: I have now updated the script with an `if(isset($child['children']))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22547/discussion-between-bjorne-malmanger-and-user1286499)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is how I would do it....

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    foreach($item['children'] as $child) {
          echo $child['stuff'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This will call first variation only. Same as my example on line `36`